# How to change theme using ThemeResources in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone

I have defined themes in `app.xaml`. it works for `Light` and `Dark` when user changes his phone theme in settings.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyAppBackground" Color="Black"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyAppAccentColor" Color="White"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyAppTextColor" Color="Red"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyAppBackground" Color="White"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyAppAccentColor" Color="Black"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyAppTextColor" Color="Yellow"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="CustomTheme1">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyAppBackground" Color="Blue"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyAppAccentColor" Color="Green"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyAppTextColor" Color="White"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

But I want to be able to change theme to `CustomTheme1` in the app. In the xaml I can set
     `RequestedTheme="Light"`

But it doesn't have my custom theme.

*It's a windows phone 8.1 app*

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can set only Light or Dark theme. There is no option to add custom themes in      RequestedTheme except to customize Light and Dark theme.

Comment: So is there anyway else to have custom themes? without ThemeResources

Comment: Sounds like a different question and I think I've seen one asked before for winrt.